# Call SQL function from Java

Tags: java, sql, date, parameters

I have a begin end block in SQL and I did something like this to call it from Java, but when I check if it executes correctly it gives me an error like this :

```
 Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1 Error Code: 17041
```

My code is this :

```
public void setDate(){
    String startDate = null, endDate = null;
    Query query = manager.createNativeQuery("Declare "
            + "dStartDate date :=  ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, - 60);"
            + "begin "
            + "schema.table.SetDateLimits( dStartDate, ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, - 1));"
            + ":END := To_Char(SYSDATE,'yyyy/mm');"
            + ":START := To_Char(dStartDate,'yyyy/mm');" + "end;");
    Object v = query.getSingleResult();
    System.out.println("The limits are " + startDate+ " " +endDate);
}
```

Does anybody know why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you should get the entire raw query running on Oracle without errors, and then try to port it into your Java code.  Don't fix a database problem in Java unless you have to.

Comment: Does that exact query get executed when passed directly to the database, e.g. via command line or a client tool? I'm also not sure whether case is a matter but your query contains `sysdate` as well as `SYSDATE`.

Comment: it gets executed via a client tool

Comment: Your code looks like JPA so which provider are you using? You might have to use a select query to get the data into the resultset.

Comment: I am using EclipseLink